# Creating a dynamic redirect by using any of Flask, Pyramid, or Bottle?

Tags: python, pyramid

I want to create a webapp that dynamically redirects to a URL, based on address that user typed. When a user visit my site by a address like this:

```
http://mydomain1.com/a1b2c3d4
```

I want redirect this user to URL:

```
http://mydomain2.com/register.php?id=a1b2c3d4&from=mydomain1.com
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yay, I love a good fight!

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound
from paste.httpserver import serve

config = Configurator()

config.add_route('redirect', '/{arg}')

def redirect_view(request):
    dst = 'http://mydomain2.com/register.php?id={id}&from={host}'
    args = {
        'id': request.matchdict['arg'],
        'host': request.host,
    }
    return HTTPFound(dst.format(**args))
config.add_view(redirect_view, route_name='redirect')

serve(config.make_wsgi_app(), host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: Thanks, but "mydomain1.com" also a parameter.

Comment: Updated to have `mydomain1.com` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Here goes my attempt, I'm almost newbie in flask, so it should have room to improve

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request
app = Flask(__name__)
host = 'domain2.org'

@app.route('/<path>')
def redirection(path):
    return redirect('http://'+host+'/register.php?id='+path+'&from='+request.host)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Edited to add the host to the from parameter

Comment: although I'll recomend some sanity checks to the path, to make sure everything is ok.

For example, someone could try to go to domain1.org/my_path&from='domain3.org'

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a Werkzeug rule using the path type :

```
host = 'domain2.org'
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def redirection(path):
    return redirect('http://%s/%s' % (host, path), code=301)
```

This can be useful if you move a site and want another site instead with redirection on others pages.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pyramid_rewrite extension (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_rewrite/) that looks unmaintained, but seems to work. I had a use case it didn't handle, though: using Configure.include() with the route_prefix parameter.

It occurred to me that the usual approach is to do URL rewrites in the server, and I was using a WSGI server from the Python standard library. How hard could it be?

Make a custom request handler class:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server, WSGIRequestHandler

class MyReqHandler(WSGIRequestHandler):
    def get_environ(self):
        env = WSGIRequestHandler.get_environ(self)

        if env['PATH_INFO'].startswith('/foo'):
           env['PATH_INFO'] = env['PATH_INFO'].replace('foo', 'bar', 1)

        return env
```

Pass it to make_server() when creating your server:

```
srvr = make_server('0.0.0.0', 6543, app, handler_class=MyReqHandler)
```

It works!

Straight-up substitution is all I needed for the problem at hand. Extending it to use regular expressions and exposing it via a nice API would be pretty straightforward.

I have another solution, that is straight-up pyramid, so it will work with some other wsgi server:

```
from pyramid.events import NewRequest, subscriber

@subscriber(NewRequest)
def mysubscriber(event):
    req = event.request

    if req.path_info.startswith('/~cfuller'):
        req.path_info = req.path_info.replace('foo', 'bar', 1)
```

That's the declarative way, and it requires a config.scan(). Imperitively, you'd do something like

```
config.add_subscriber(mysubscriber, NewRequest)
```

See http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/events.html for the skinny on events.